# Does Parjanya japa really bring rain?

Tags: belief, japa, homam

There is a modern business going on now a days in the homa, japa in all temples nearby our places.

There was a traditional belief that by doing `Parijanya Japa` will lead to rainfall in barren lands. Is that applicable in today's modern world as well?

Comment: Why not? Vedas and homas does not have expiry date.They are sanatana.

Comment: Yes, parijanya japa and varuna yaga lead to rainfall, cos vedas/homas are eternal, but what people forget is that vedas are AN EXACT SCIENCE. If you don't follow ALL rules, no rain will fall, even what is scheduled to fall may not e.g. during some yagas, if priest gets itch on body, they should not scratch with hand, but with special wood stick, should not have any salt in food, should observe strict brahmacharyam, the materials used must be spotless etc. All this is near-impossible in this day and age. In Ramayana, Kumbhakarna says fighting against Rama is like performing yagam in Kali yuga.

Comment: First check if the priests have shikha (tuft in back of head), wear kachha -style dhoti, do sandhya vandanam & gayatri japa every day, do not eat in restaurants, or do not work in corporate offices on the side etc. and most importantly, do not negotiate a fees up front, or advertise grandly on websites & bill boards, and are not sponsored by politicians or industrialists who have gained money by ill-means. Most likely nowadays, if yagas are being done as a business, it is exactly that - a business. But all that aside, if people do it with BHAKTI and offer results to God, anything is possible.

Comment: @ram "In Ramayana, Kumbhakarna says fighting against Rama is like performing yagam in Kali yuga."  Is that in the Kamba Ramayana?  Because I don't think it's there in the Valmiki Ramayana.

Answer (score 2):

In the book, *[Hindu Dharma: The Universal Way of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8172760558)* <sup>§</sup>, [Swami Chandrasekarendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) cautions these japas and homas don't work always:

> **It may be that sometimes the Varuna japa does not succeed in bringing rains.** But this is no reason why all mantras should be rejected outright as of no value. Sick people die even after the regular administration of medicine. For this reason do we condemn medical science as worthless? We have an explanation for the patient's failure to recover: his illness and reached such an advanced stage that no medicine could be of any avail. **Similarly, no mantra is of any help when it has to contend against the working of powerful karma.** There is also another reason. If you are not strict about your diet, the medicine taken may not work. Similarly, if we are lax in the observance of certain rules, the mantras will not produce the desired result.
>
> [Hindu Dharma » The Vedic Religion And Varna Dharma » Preserving the Vedas: Why it is a Lifetime Mission]

I tend to believe that there is 50-50 chance of any japa or homa bringing rain. When the homa does yield rain, people tend to attribute it to the homa. But [correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation). The homas that don't bring rain are not reported by people in the same way when it "really worked."

Ironically, in 2015, when Telangana Chief Minister K. Chandrasekhar Rao was conducting a mahāyāga for universal peace, a fire [broke out](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Fire-breaks-out-at-yagna-organized-by-Telangana-CM-K-Chandrasekhar-Rao/articleshow/50341683.cms):

> HYDERABAD: A fire broke out at the 'yagna' organized by Telangana chief minister K Chandrasekhar Rao on Sunday afternoon.
>
> ...
>
> The incident occurred at around 1.30pm at Erravelli village in neighbouring Medak district when fire, that erupted from the 'homagundam' (pedestal for sacred fire), spread to the 'Yagashala' shed (made of grass), they said.
>
> ...
>
> "No one was injured in the incident and all the people present there were immediately evacuated. The flames have been brought under control," the DSP said.
>
> ...
>
> According to reports, about 2,000 priests from Telangana, Andhra Pradesh, Maharashtra, Karnataka and Tamil Nadu are taking part in the mega 'yagam' being performed for universal peace.
>
> Rao has spent about Rs 7 crore on performing 'Ayutha Maha Chandi Yagna' in the state for universal peace.

---

EDIT:

The reason I quoted the above news article is to simply show that despite the best intentions a yajña can go wrong. All the more reason to believe it's a hit-and-miss. Also, there is no way to tell if a yajña done for "universal peace" really worked or not.

Here's [an example](http://capstrat.in/gurusangamam/allguruspages/chinnajeeyar/about_chinnajeeyar.html) of a yajña that seems to have worked:

> For about four years i.e., from 1985 to 1988 there was a continuous and constant failure of rains in Andhra Pradesh. The state in general and Hyderabad in particular were reeling under the conditions of drought.
>
> Sri Swamiji (Chinna Jeeyar) was merciful enough to perform a Varuna Yagna in Hyderabad for a period of 9 days. From the last day of the yagnam (i.e. Poornahuti day) miraculously there were heavy rains.

The bio however doesn't tell if Chinna Jeeyar Swami performed other such Varuna yajñas and if there were "heavy rains" immediately following the other yajñas.

<sup>§</sup>  <sub>An older and copyright-free version of this book is available for free [here](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part3/chap8.htm).</sub>

Comment: is there any need to mention fire incident that happened in Yajna conducted by KCR?

Comment: I didn't understand what is ironical. KCR took it positively. He said nature itself conducted poornahuti which is our task to do. Everything is for good. He didn't take it as a bad sign.

Comment: Do you believe that if the yaga is done with ritualistic purity and doesn't have to contend against karma, it will yield rain ?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, it is relevant. Because if the fire was big enough, some people could've died (going against the purpose of the whole yagna) and the yagna would be abandoned.

Comment: @SreeCharan It is ironical because all those priests and people who had 100% belief in the yagna shouldn't have run away and faced their fate. I'm not surprised KCR didn't take it as a bad sign.

Comment: @ram "ritualistic purity" - how do you ensure that? If it rains, the yagna was strictly according to 'rules' and if it doesn't rain, some rule was broken? I tend to think 'karma theory' is always readily available to explain why a yagna failed. Once and for all someone should try conducting a yagna in a desert to prove its efficacy.

Comment: @sv, you ensure it the same way a scientist ensures purity in a semiconductor lab, or in a pharmaceutical lab. There have been yagnas conducted, even within past 50 years, that lead to rains.

Comment: @ram 'the same way a scientist ensures purity' - good analogy, but a scientist can tell why the experiment went wrong, why a rocket launch failed etc after postmortem. If a priest cannot explain why his yajña failed 5 out of 10 times, what error he committed, the problem may not be with the priest but the concept of yajña itself. I wonder why more & more people are running to Infertility clinics instead of doing a Putrakameshti if it really works? Even if Putrakameshti had a 50% success rate, it would've been very popular in this day & age. But it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @sv, the point of contention is not whether they work *nowadays* (although that is what OP asked), but whether they work at all. I absolutely believe they do because Vedas are infallible. Just because priests today don't have the discipline to follow the rules, or are not knowledgeable enough, it does not demean the homas in any way. The sun may shine on a ditch, but that does not degrade the sun.

Comment: http://www.articlesfactory.com/articles/metaphysical/inducing-rainfall-even-in-very-dry-arid-areas-via-mantra-energy.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=C26lbOuDIbYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=prayers&f=true) is one instance where Varuna Japa(similar to Parjanya Japa) brought rain.

In his book when I saw Tirupati Balaji, P.V.R.K Prasad says once when there was extreme water scarcity in Tirupati,  all the ponds, lakes and wells were empty and the main water source of Tirupati temple, Gogarbham reservoir was also emptied. So, then excecitive officer of the temple, P.V.R.K Prasad, decided to perform Varuna Japa under the guidence of Sri Uppuluri Ganapathi Sastry. Japa lasted for three days, some moments after the Japa was concluded, it started raining and the rain continued till the next day morning.

Comment: Were there other times when this person/priest P.V.R.K Prasad performed Varuna Japa? Did it bring rain every single time?

Comment: @sv. No, I have read only half of that book, and only one incident is mentioned.