# Are there any instances where Putra Kameshti Yajna really worked?

Tags: belief, yajna

It is believed that if a couple remained childless or doesn't have a male child, performing Putra Kameshti Yajna will result in producing offspring, especially a male offspring. Now, my question is, are there any instances / examples of Putra Kameshti Yajna really worked?

Comment: Examples from scriptures or?

Comment: @Rickross No, real life examples like this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/does-parjanya-japa-really-bring-rain/28749#28749

Comment: When my grandfather was young, studying in Tiruvarur government school, then Zamindar of Tiruvarur Tyagaraja Mudaliyar was infertile and didn't have any offspring. According to the British law(it was in late 1930s I think so), if a Zamindar didn't have any child, the properties of him would be taken over by the government. So, he consulted H.H. Chandrasekara Saraswati Swamigal of Kanchi mutt, who performed Putra Kameshti Yajna for him which resulted in pregnancy. This was told to me by my late grandfather.

Comment: These are matters of faith and no example can be cited. Even if cited, we can't verify its authenticity. Answers to this question will lead to user's opinions and personal experiences. Hence, answers which cite personal experiences are not welcome here and are subjected to deletion. Asking for user's experiences and opinions is not a good question and closable.  See [help/dont-ask].

Comment: I think Dasharatha did it. Also rAmAnuja s parents

Comment: Drupada did it and Dhrishtadyumna was born...but if u r not askig from scriptures then this Q is not on topic...we don't provide answer from current affairs...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't want answer from scriptures.

Comment: @YDS Not everything on this site can be/needs to be answered using scriptures.

Comment: It is a opinion based question. You cannot find a person who is well versed in putra kamesthi yaga in current scenario. Voting to close.